# Out of memory exception while loading image within a listbox in windows phone Application?

Tags: windows, image, windows-phone-8, binding

I am new to Windows Phone App Development. I came across an application in which I should load some Images from the server and show it in a listbox. There are more than 50 images to show in different pages, but after loading some images its showing out of memory exception and the application is crashing. So please help me out from this issue. I found same type of questions in stackoverflow, and I followed those but still I am unable to solve the issue.

I am loading the images by binding the source within a listboxItem Template. Code used to implement this is given below.

**XAML Code**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="6 12">                                                        
                        <ListBox Name="ListEventImages">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <!--<VirtualizingStackPanel CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent="VirtualizingStackPanel_CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent_1"/>-->
                                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="20,0,20,0" ItemHeight="180" ItemWidth="140" Width="460" Height="Auto"/>
                                    <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>-->
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>                                    
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="0 0 0 0">
                                        <spin:Spinner Visibility="Visible" />
                                        <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding EventImage}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="160" Width="120" 
                                                Tap="imageTap">                                              
                                        </Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
```

**CS Code**

```
void LoadingImage()
{
ListEventImages.ItemsSource = null;

                    ObservableCollection<EventImages> lstEvent = null;
                    lstEvent = new ObservableCollection<EventImages>();

                    var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath);
                    ImageList lsLeaderImg = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ImageList;

                    var queryEventImages = from mImages in db.Table<video_image>() where mImages._sub_video_id == lsLeaderImg.SVidoeId orderby mImages._position ascending select mImages;
                    foreach (var objEvent in queryEventImages)
                    {                           
                        lstEvent.Add(new EventImages(objEvent._url, objEvent._caption));
                    }
                    ListEventImages.ItemsSource = lstEvent;
}

public class EventImages
    {
        public string EventImage { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public EventImages(string _url, string _caption)
        {
            try
            {

                EventImage = _url;
                Caption = _caption;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried using GC.Collect() but still its crashing. Please help me out. Thanx in advance.

Comment: The virtualizing stackpanel isn't helping in this case?

Comment: Yes I tried, but after scrolling down the top images in the lists are becoming null and its not loading again. But I want to load those images again if  user scrolls up. So please help me out.